# Commits not being pushed to origin

Tags: git, gitlab

I changed some files locally, added them, and committed them. When I try to push this branch to origin so that I can open a merge request, it seems that it isn't pushing any changes since the Total is 0

```
~/work/pr $ git commit -m "something"
[master e9bd370] something
 5 files changed, 86 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 arrows.png
 create mode 100644 foo.html
~/work/pr $ git push origin newbranch
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@hosted.gitlab.repo:user/my-repo.git
 * [new branch]      newbranch -> newbranch
```

The above lets me open a new merge request on GitLab webpage, however, says "nothing to merge". Which is because the `Total 0` in the above terminal output.

Comment: It looks like you were working on `master`. Did you run `git checkout -b newbranch` before doing any work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks totally normal. Your "newbranch" clearly has nothing new to add to the conversation.

I assume you were here:

```
git checkout master        # whatever the current branch is, assuming master
```

You probably meant to do, starting from above:

```
git commit -m "Something"
git branch -f newbranch    # re-position the new branch
git push origin newbranch
```

That's not the best practice, though. You should have done:

```
git checkout newbranch
# get the "newbranch" updated with the latest available "good stuff"
git merge master
# work on something and commit
git commit -m "Something"
git status
# "git graph" here would be very useful to look at (see extra hint, below)
git push origin newbranch
```

PS. Extra tip - Use a handy alias `git graph` to visualize your branches while working, basically a super-powered `git log` / `git status` (more like log, less like status). https://sites.google.com/site/sudokillall9/articles/gitgraphvariants

Answer (score 1):

According to your commit result, it looks like you were on `master` when you made the commit.

Since you are committing it to `master`, instead of `newbranch`, nothing in `newbranch` was changed.

You need to checkout the `newbranch` branch before committing / pushing if you want to update that one.